# How to make multiple slider move horizontally on scroll simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, css-animations, framer-motion

I am making a website in Next.js and using FramerMotion. I'm unable to make an animation. Basically there will be three rows of images, and on scrolling down row 1 & 3 will move to left and the row 2 will move to right. Vice versa will happen on scrolling up.

I need help, on how can I do it work.

[image]

Comment: I recommend using library. I normally use react-scroll-parallax but if all you want is the feature you talk about you could use  something more simple like paroller.js